# Plotly offline charts with dropdown in flask

Tags: python, flask, plotly

I am trying to render a plotly chart in flask. Everything works fine when I use a normal chart. The issue arises when trying to use charts with drop-down menus. In that case I get a blank webpage.

My code is below.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import json
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def dashboards():
    # Read in the Data via Pandas
    df = pd.read_csv('raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/volcano.csv')
    data = [go.Surface(z=df.values.tolist(), colorscale='Viridis')]

    layout = go.Layout(
        width=800,
        height=900,
        autosize=False,
        margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0),
        scene=dict(
            xaxis=dict(
                gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                showbackground=True,
                backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
            ),
            yaxis=dict(
                gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                showbackground=True,
                backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230, 230)'
            ),
            zaxis=dict(
                gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                showbackground=True,
                backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
            ),
            aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.7),
            aspectmode='manual'
        )
    )

    updatemenus = list([
        dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(
                    args=['type', 'surface'],
                    label='3D Surface',
                    method='restyle'
                ),
                dict(
                    args=['type', 'heatmap'],
                    label='Heatmap',
                    method='restyle'
                )
            ]),
            direction='down',
            pad={'r': 10, 't': 10},
            showactive=True,
            x=0.1,
            xanchor='left',
            y=1.1,
            yanchor='top'
        ),
    ])

    annotations = list([
        dict(text='Trace type:', x=0, y=1.085, yref='paper', align='left', 
     showarrow=False)
    ])
    layout['updatemenus'] = updatemenus
    layout['annotations'] = annotations

    fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
    # Convert the figures to JSON
    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

    # Render the Template
    return render_template('dashboard.html', graphJSON=graphJSON)


   if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

HTML template is

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Fruit Plot</h3>
<div id="graph-0"></div>

</body>


<footer>
    <!-- D3.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Plotly.js -->
    <script src="https://d14fo0winaifog.cloudfront.net/plotly-basic.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
  var fig = {{graphJSON | safe}};
  Plotly.plot("graph-0", fig.data, fig.layout);
    </script>
</footer>

</html>
```

I get a blank page.

can anyone pls help?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please have a look at your code again, the `read_csv` line looks odd.

Comment: thanks for the observation . it should be df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/volcano.csv')

Comment: You can edit your question and fix the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not the dropdown menus but you are using a 'basic' version of Ploty. (I have no idea what that really is)

If you change your HTML template to include.

```
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

instead of the other plotly version, the code should work.